# How to get the file name Bitmap object?

Tags: .net, string, bitmap

Here is my C# code:

```
    public static void FilterNoises(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmp);
        img.PyrUp().PyrDown();
        img.Save(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Road Images\Filtered Images\" +   "filename.extension");
    }
```

I need to get the file name and extansion from bmp object.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You will have to specify your own name here.

Comment: You knew the name back in the code that loaded the bitmap.  Assuming it actually came from a file, no such requirement.  You'll need to preserve that name yourself, Bitmap won't do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the file name and extension from when you loaded the bitmap, you can get the filename directly from the Bitmap object itself

```
var filename = @"C:\Filename.bmp";
var bitmap = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName, true));
```

Comment: Craig,how can i get filename diractly from the Bitmam?can u give me some example please?

Comment: You cant get it from the Bitmap object itself, i would imagine at some point you will have loaded a file into the bitmap. At that point you would have the filename, either that or you would have generated the bitmap in memory, if that is the case, it would have never had a filename.